# 1С - Как значением в табличной части изменить нужные галочки?

Tags: 1с

Есть код:

```
    Запрос = Новый Запрос;
    Запрос.Текст =
    "ВЫБРАТЬ
     |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка КАК Ссылка,
     |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.Номер КАК Номер,
     |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.ПодразделениеОрганизации КАК ПодразделениеОрганизации,
     |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.ОС.ОсновноеСредство,
     |ИнвентаризацияОС.ОсновноеСредство,
     |РегСведПерв.ИнвентарныйНомер КАК ИнвНомер
    |ИЗ
       |Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС.ОС КАК ИнвентаризацияОС,
         |ВНУТРЕННЕЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрСведений.ПервоначальныеСведенияОСБухгалтерскийУчет.СрезПервых КАК РегСведПерв
         |ПО ИнвентаризацияОС.ОсновноеСредство = РегСведПерв.ОсновноеСредство
    |ГДЕ                                           
     |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.ПодразделениеОрганизации = &ПодразделениеОрганизации
     |И ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.Номер = &НомерОрганизации
     |И ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.ОС.ОсновноеСредство = РегСведПерв.ОсновноеСредство";  

    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр(
        "ПодразделениеОрганизации",
        Справочники.ПодразделенияОрганизаций.НайтиПоНаименованию(ВыберитеНазваниеОрганизации.ПодразделениеОрганизации)
    );                                 
    
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр(
    "НомерОрганизации",
    ВыберитеНазваниеОрганизации.Номер
    );
    
          
      РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();
    ВыборкаДокументов = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать();
    
ИнвЧисло = Новый Массив();
ИнвЧисло.Добавить(1);
ИнвЧисло.Добавить(0);
ИнвЧисло.Добавить(1);    
НумерИнв = 0;
    
    Пока ВыборкаДокументов.Следующий() Цикл
        
            Док = ВыборкаДокументов.Ссылка.ПолучитьОбъект();
            
            Для каждого Стр из Док.ОС Цикл
                
                
                
            Если Стр.ОсновноеСредство = Справочники.ОсновныеСредства.НайтиПоНаименованию(ВыборкаДокументов.ОсновноеСредство) Тогда  
                
            
                Стр.НаличиеФактическое = ИнвЧисло[НумерИнв+1];
                
                Сообщить(Стр.НаличиеФактическое); 
    
            КонецЕсли;
                
           КонецЦикла;
           Док.Записать();
           
           Реквизит1 = ВыборкаДокументов.Ссылка;
           
        КонецЦикла;
```

Как в 1С значением в табличной части изменить нужные галочки? (в инвентаризации ОС, когда открываем нужный документ)

У меня галочки проставляются для всех, а нужно проставить галочки для конкретных ОС, т.е. там, где единички (из массива ИнвЧисло).

Comment: Ничего не понятно из описания.

Comment: @Sagittarius https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtnsJ.png
На этом скриншоте показал пример. Есть два ОС. Как первому проставить галочку, а второму нет. Для примера в массиве `ИнвЧисло` есть значения `1` и `0`. Я их здесь подставлял, предварительно увеличив индекс массива в цикле с помощью `НумерИнв`, т.е. так: `ИнвЧисло[НумерИнв+1]`. Т.е. с циклом я думал что сперва подставится `1` (для первого ОС), а потом `0` (для второго ОС). Но здесь у обеих единичка, т.е. галочка для всех подставляется. Как сделать правильно?

Comment: Используйте для заполнения массива Ложь и Истина, вместо 0 и 1. Должно будет отработать корректно. Но у меня один вопрос, так как похоже что вы строите грандиозный велосипед с костылями. Как вы получаете список номенклатур, для которых необходимо проставить наличие и определяете в каких строках ставить флаги?

Answer (score 0):

`НаличиеФактическое` скорее всего типа `Булево`, а записываем туда `Число` ???

*Стр.НаличиеФактическое = ИнвЧисло[НумерИнв+1];  // Надо записывать Истина/Ложь*

Comment: Даже с единицами и нулями галочка снимается и ставится. На всякий преобразовал тип. Пробовал и такой вариант: Если Стр.НаличиеФактическое <Булево(Число(МассивКоличества[ЧислоИнв + 1])) Тогда  
  Стр.НаличиеФактическое = Истина;
     Сообщить(Стр.НаличиеФактическое); 
  КонецЕсли;

Comment: проверку:  'Если Стр.ОсновноеСредство = Справочники.ОсновныеСредства.НайтиПоНаименованию(ВыборкаДокументов.ОсновноеСредство)' исправить на 'Если Стр.ОсновноеСредство = ВыборкаДокументов.ОсновноеСредство' ; Не понятно совершенно причём тут Массив с 0 и 1 ?

Comment: С помощью массива 0 и 1 пытаюсь подставить истину и ложь

Answer (score 0):

Тут нужно всё переделать !

1 в запрос добавляем `НомерСтроки`;

2 в запрос добавляем `УПОРЯДОЧИТЬ ПО ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка, ИнвентаризацияОС.Номерстроки`

```
Запрос.Текст =
    "ВЫБРАТЬ
     |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка КАК Ссылка,
     |ИнвентаризацияОС.НомерСтроки,  // 1 ------------------------
     |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.Номер КАК Номер,
     |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.ПодразделениеОрганизации КАК ПодразделениеОрганизации,
     |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.ОС.ОсновноеСредство,
     |ИнвентаризацияОС.ОсновноеСредство,
     |РегСведПерв.ИнвентарныйНомер КАК ИнвНомер
    |ИЗ
       |Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС.ОС КАК ИнвентаризацияОС,
         |ВНУТРЕННЕЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрСведений.ПервоначальныеСведенияОСБухгалтерскийУчет.СрезПервых КАК РегСведПерв
         |ПО ИнвентаризацияОС.ОсновноеСредство = РегСведПерв.ОсновноеСредство
    |ГДЕ                                           
     |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.ПодразделениеОрганизации = &ПодразделениеОрганизации
     |И ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.Номер = &НомерОрганизации
     |И ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.ОС.ОсновноеСредство = РегСведПерв.ОсновноеСредство
    |УПОРЯДОЧИТЬ ПО ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка, ИнвентаризацияОС.НомерСтроки // 2 ----";
```

3 нам необходимо контролировать момент когда в цикле мы переходим к новому Документу; Чтобы это работало ВАЖНО что бы выборка была отсортирована по Документу (`УПОРЯДОЧИТЬ ПО ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка`)

4 в цикле по табличной части, проверяем `Стр.НомерСтроки` и НомерСтроки из выборки, так останавливаемся на нужной строке (это лучше чем проверка на Стр.ОсновноеСредство, т.к. в таб-части может быть несколько одинаковых ОС)

5 проверку на совпадение ОС напиши САМ (предварительно добавь нужные ОС в Массив)

```
ТекДокумент = Неопределено;
Пока ВыборкаДокументов.Следующий() Цикл
   Если ТекДокумент = Неопределено Тогда  // 3 --- вначале берем ПЕРВЫЙ документ
      ТекДокумент = ВыборкаДокументов.Ссылка;
      Док = ТекДокумент.ПолучитьОбъект();
   КонецЕсли;

   Если ТекДокумент <> ВыборкаДокументов.Ссылка Тогда // 3 --- Сменился документ
      Док.Записать();   // Записываем все наши изменения в документе (галочки)
      ТекДокумент = ВыборкаДокументов.Ссылка;
      Док = ТекДокумент.ПолучитьОбъект();
   КонецЕсли;
     
   // Сейчас Док содержит ДокументОбъект   
   // Док = ВыборкаДокументов.Ссылка.ПолучитьОбъект();
            
   Для каждого Стр из Док.ОС Цикл
      // Переходим к ОС из запроса, для этого проверим НомерСтроки
      Если Стр.НомерСтроки = ВыборкаДокументов.НомерСтроки Тогда // 4 ---
         // сейчас на нужной строке ТЧ 
         // -- проверку на совпадение с ОС из массива напиши САМ --
         //Если Стр.ОсновноеСредство = ОСизМассива Тогда
         Стр.НаличиеФактическое = Истина;  // ставим галочку
         //КонецЕсли;

         Прервать; // выходим из цикла, остальные НомерСтроки не интересуют

      КонецЕсли;
   КонецЦикла;
КонецЦикла;
Если ТекДокумент <> Неопределено Тогда
   Док.Записать();   // Записываем все наши изменения в ПОСЛЕДНЕМ документе (галочки)
КонецЕсли;
```

Тот код который ты запостил в вопросе, *несколько раз открывает один и тот же Документ, несколько раз записывает ...* поэтому нужно переделать, чтобы Открытие/Запись документа были **один** раз !